# Adjusting for change in exposure (not outcome)

Tags: regression

In a cross-sectional study we want to determine how a test affected the physical activity scores (PAS), but the test (which takes about 50 minutes) is a difference or change in a blood oxygen after giving drug X intravenously (that is, blood oxygen is measured at baseline (before administering drug X) that is preX and after drug X that is postX and the difference in the two is the test result that is, postX - preX). The linear reg model here is:

```
reg PAS change
```

where change is postX - preX.

How does controlling for baseline blood oxygen levels affect the model and/or results? That is, adding preX in the model this way:

```
reg PAS change preX
```

Would the preX be included in the model if the change had been dichotomized into positive and negative values, a variable Dich_Change?

```
reg PAS Dich_Change preX
```

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y =$ PAS, $X_b = $ preX, and $X_a$ postX.
You can fit a model as
$$Y = \alpha +\beta_a X_a +\beta_b X_b +\epsilon$$

Based on this model you can check if the preX or PostX or both of them have effect on PAS.

By testing the null hypothesis $H_o: \beta_a + \beta_b = 0$, you can check if only change in a blood oxygen has effect on PAS, regardless preX or PostX.

Comment: Answered your question? understandable?